# Are there any benefits to inheriting from an abstract template class?

Tags: class, templates, inheritance, abstract, radix

By that I mean doing the following:

```
template<class Type> class Foo {
public:
... // Code Here.
};

class Bar : public Foo<Type> {
public:
...
};
```

Where *Type* when declaring class Bar is actually a type (int, bool, etc..) or a type created before-hand.

If this question is too vague, or if it's already been answered please let me know.

Comment: Is your question resolved? If so, could you please upvote the answer and accept it? If not, please edit your question with further details.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a language feature is useful or not, really depends on how and where you *use* it. For inheriting from a templated abstract template, here's one hypothetical scenario that I can think of, where it *may* be useful.

```
template <typename Type> class Gadget {
public:
    string name() = 0;
};

class SmartPhone : public Gadget<Phone> {
public:
    string name() { return "I am a smart phone"; }
};

class SportsCar : public Gadget<Car> {
public:
    string name() { return "I am a sports car"; }
};

vector<Gadget*> inventory;
inventory.push_back(new SmartPhone());
inventory.push_back(new SportsCar());
// etc ...
```

Note that this is likely not the best way to implement it, but my point is that you can always find some use for everything. :)